# How to simultaneously move and scale 3D object at runtime in Unity?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I need to **move** and **scale** 3D object at runtime in Unity.

I can move it like this:

```
void Update(){

public Transform target_1;
float relocationSpeed = 10;
float step = relocationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

MyObject.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (MyObject.transform.position, target_1.position, step);
}
```

I can scale it up using coroutine like this:

```
float scaleSize = 20;

IEnumerator ScaleUpMyObject(){

        for (var i = 0; i < scaleSize; i++) {

            MyObject.transform.localScale += new Vector3 (1, 1, 1);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);

        }
}
```

But what would be the best way to move and scale my object **simultaneously**?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Without changing too much of your original code, you could do something like this

```
public Vector3 wantedSize = new Vector3(5, 5, 5);
void Update()
{
    float relocationSpeed = 10;
    float step = relocationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    MyObject.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(MyObject.transform.position, target_1.position, step);
    MyObject.transform.localScale = Vector3.MoveTowards(MyObject.transform.localScale, wantedSize, step);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will test it! Also, If you mean there is a better way to do it than in my code, I would be grateful for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the animator for that, here is an example.

[Unity 3D object animation example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V394gbdG4zQ)

Also you can use a library like iTween (free on the asset store) to animate the vectors of position and scale, has transition options too, for you to not only translate linearly (ease in and out in quad, bounce, exponentialy, etc).

[Unity Asset Store - iTween](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/itween-84)